# How to find biggest folder in CentOS using a command

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space-utilization

Our disk on our VPS is somehow magically full, I was manually looking for any big files, even used a command to print all files bigger then 500MB, I got no results.

Is there a command which would search or print folder names, which are bigger then 500mb perhaps?

p.s.: I use CentOS 5.7

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just bear in mind that you problem might not even be big files. It could just as easily be large numbers of small files. For a quick check compare your free space to your free inodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really enjoy using [the `ncdu` utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to provide a graphical representation of folder and subfolder usage on a system...

[image]

It's used in a similar manner as `du`, but makes it easy to navigate directories. The version for your OS is available via [source tarball](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) or from the [EPEL repository](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/epel-x86_64/ncdu-1.5-1.el5.x86_64.rpm.html).

Answer (score 2):

As @ewwhite mentioned, you can also use "du" and manual traversing of the directories if you can't install an application:

```
cd /
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

This will give you a list, in ascending order of folders and their corresponding size. You can then manually drill down finding folders.

```
du -h # outputs in human readable format
sort -h # sort by human readable format
sort -r # reverse on top
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a stock utility that does what you need.

For directories, there's a perl script that does what you need in this LinuxJournal article

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-find-directories-over-certain-size

For files find would be your friend.